# no such repository on migrating to a new cvs server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, migration, cvs, rhel

I am moving from cvsserv1 to cvsserv2. I am running cvs1.11 on current server on RHEL. I am moving to cvsserv2 which is running ubuntu 12. This is my procedure to port cvs:

1. zip entire repository on cvsserv1
2. move zip to cvsserv2
3. extract zip to /home/users on cvsserv2.
4. setup cvs service on cvsserve2 in pserver mode.
5. initialize repository on /home/users/cvsroot by using "cvs -d /home/users/cvsroot init"
6. connect to cvsserv2 from eclipse using anonymous access to do a test checkout.

I am failing on step6 with the error message "no such repository". What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I tried to change the above method, by adopting this http://mazanatti.info/archives/67/ and I was partially successful.

At step 3 (as in that link), after initializing repo on cvsserv2, I copied my repository to /var/lib/cvsd/project1, overwriting CVSROOT folder. Now, after finishing all steps, I was able to connect successfully. However, when I try to check out, I don't see any branches. When I tried to Refresh Tags, I receive the following error:

[image]

What is going wrong?

Comment: Please note, bounty will be awarded to the answer that addresses the issue in the screenshot.

Comment: 28 views and no comments?

Comment: Sorry, not a real contribution, but can you enlighten me on why on earth you're using CVS? I can hardly imagine that's deliberately :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured this one out. For those who might encounter this issue again, here's how I managed to identify and fix it:

Eclipse's cvs client sucks - it doesn't give you much information. (I could be wrong, may be it writes some debug info to eclipse log file - still, I think that error message should have been more descriptive). Anyway, I obtained TortoiseCVS and attempted a checkout and it failed with an error message on the lines of -"**failed to obtain dir lock in repository `/home/cvsroot/foo'**. This is not the exact message, but it was something like that.

So, all I had to do, was go into my cvs dump from cvsserv1, look for references to that directory (which is a valid path on cvsserv1 but not cvsserv2). I found a reference to it in **config** file under CVSROOT folder. It was assigned to a property called **LockDir**. This property was referring to a /home/cvsroot/foo on the older server as a lock directory. All I had to do was comment out this property and restart cvsd. Everything started working just fine after this!